# How would I play input from the mic through speaker while a key is pressed?

Tags: windows-7, windows, audio, autohotkey, microphone

I like to play games with my headphones on, and it feels really weird to not hear myself when I speak. The `V` key is what I use to transmit, so is there an AutoHotkey script or other program to listen to the microphone while a key is pressed?

I'm on Windows 7.

Comment: What have you researched or tried so far? The function may be limited by hardware, so more information on your set up would be helpful. Not all sound devices are capable.

Comment: I looked for different functions of AHK but there was no function to tap into the microphone. All I need is a background tool to listen for a key, and when pressed, plays the microphone input into the mixer (like the "listen" option in the control panel). It seems relatively simple, so it might be pretty easy to code it myself. I'd just rather not learn another language for one task that could be doable with other means.